# Strange state of docker on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Command

```
$ docker-machine ls
```

gives me

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM
default            virtualbox   Timeout
```

And If I run start.sh in Docker Toolbox I get

```
                    ##         .
              ## ## ##        ==
           ## ## ## ## ##    ===
       /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
       \______ o           __/
         \    \         __/
          \____\_______/

host is not running
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP
```

What does this state mean?

Comment: Hey did you get any solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet (

Comment: Also seeing this timeout state after restarting my virtual box host adapters

Answer (score 1):

**To solve** the issue go to your Virtual Box and **delete the virtual machine** altogether.
Then **launch your Docker Quickstart Terminal**. It creates the VM from scratch  if it's not present and connects to it.

I saw this after altering my Virtual Box Host Adapters (changed IPs).

Comment: The problem with deleting the virtual machine altogether is that you then have to reinstall all the apps that you installed - what a pain, because when you docker run it has to also download all the images again. There has to be a better way than this

Answer (score 1):

Docker machine gets timeout when we switch between wifi-networks/VPN. If we switch back to the same network where docker container was initiated, we can get back the docker-machine to running state.

If your not sure what network you started your docker-machine, then just restarting your computer must fix the problem.